# Date filter - default to show a subset of recent results unless the user chooses to include old results (Sharepoint 2013 Search)

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, datepicker

Currently in the search results we display the date refiner which includes all results.

[image: Current]

We want to by default display only results from the last year, and only include older results when the user moves the slider to the left, i.e. after entering and searching for a search term, the modified date refiner should look like this:

[image: Desired]

with the option to include older results.
This is because we have a lot of historic content that "clutters" our search results, but may occassionally be useful to the right user.

What steps do we need to take to implement this?